# Listview crash the application Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I comment a line from the list view widget or app it works, but when I uncomment it it doesn't appear at all ...

It is a listview to render a notification list that you receive via api, api is working normally with the future builder, but when I add the listbuilder it stops working ...

[image: Image without listview]
[image: Image with listview]

**CODE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mais_mob/src/shared/models/notifications_model.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  String _search;
  int _page = 0;
  Future<List<NotificationModel>> _getGifs() async {
    http.Response response;

    response = await http.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/notifications/get/f331dfd0-cae4-410d-9700-b9ec72c48d7c");
    List myModels;
    myModels = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
        .map((i) => NotificationModel.fromJson(i))
        .toList();

    return myModels;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _future());
  }

  _future() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _getGifs(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 280.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 56, 0, 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, left: 20.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 200.0,
                            width: 310.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.1)),
                                ]),
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    width: 100.0,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/image/profile/profile3.jpg"),
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(50.0),
                                        ),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black12
                                                  .withOpacity(0.2),
                                              blurRadius: 10.0,
                                              spreadRadius: 2.0)
                                        ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "user['name']",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontFamily: "Sofia",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                      fontSize: 20.0),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "user['email']",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black38,
                                      fontFamily: "Sofia",
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                      fontSize: 16.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 25.0, top: 40.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Notificações",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Sofia",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // ListView.builder(
                  //     itemCount: 1,
                  //     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  //       return ListTile(
                  //         title: Text(snapshot.data[index].id),
                  //         subtitle: Text('x'),
                  //       );
                  //     }),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

**Log terminal**

flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
flutter: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
flutter: Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical
flutter: viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
flutter: typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
flutter: If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
flutter: there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
flutter: instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
flutter: the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
flutter:
flutter: The relevant error-causing widget was:
flutter:   ListView file:///Users/lucas/www1/mais_mob/lib/src/pages/dashboard/profile.dart:149:28
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      RenderViewport.performResize. (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1172:15)
flutter: #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1233:6)
flutter: #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1703:9)
flutter: #3      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #15     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:744:15)
flutter: #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #17     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:497:13)
flutter: #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1724:7)
flutter: #31     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:163:11)
flutter: #32     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:477:7)
flutter: #33     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:232:7)
flutter: #34     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:391:14)
flutter: #35     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1584:7)
flutter: #36     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
flutter: #37     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:344:19)
flutter: #38     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:774:13)
flutter: #39     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
flutter: #40     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
flutter: #41     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
flutter: #42     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
flutter: #46     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
flutter: #47     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#7ca7e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
flutter:   needs compositing
flutter:   creator: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#8349f] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ←
flutter:     _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#91c65] ←
flutter:     _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#fd66b] ← Scrollable ←
flutter:     ⋯
flutter:   parentData:  (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=414.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
flutter:   size: MISSING
flutter:   axisDirection: down
flutter:   crossAxisDirection: right
flutter:   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#09283(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
flutter:     ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> BouncingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#87e45,
flutter:     ScrollDirection.idle)
flutter:   anchor: 0.0
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:     center child: RenderSliverPadding#68fac NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter:       child: RenderSliverList#0a754 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#7ca7e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#7ca7e NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#26c9e relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#4973c relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#cdd75 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#b1e5a relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#18a2b relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#39c4e relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#041d2 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#b5a7c relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#9907c relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#9654a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#7ea85 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#44215 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#11392 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#c667c relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#b5a7c relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you didn't give the ListView.builder a height.
You can solve it by wrapping your `ListView` in a `Container` and give the `Container` a `height` and `width` property.

Check the code below, It works perfectly:

```
Container(
      // give it your desired height here
      height: 500,
      // give it your desired height here
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].id),
            subtitle: Text('x'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when trying to nest a Listview or a ListView.builder inside a Column.

You can put the Listview or a ListView.builder using Expanded.

```
Expanded( 
    child: ListView()
)
```

OR

You can put the Listview or a ListView.builder using SizedBox and set a value to the 'height' parameter of the SizedBox. The height will be fixed.

```
SizedBox(
    height: 150,
    child: ListView()
)
```

OR

You can set true to shrinkWrap property of the ListView.

```
ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a height that why it is throwing this error.Either wrap it in a Container as suggested bu @Random Guru, or add it as a child of `Expanded`.

```
Expanded(
 child:ListView.Builder(...)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it also didn't work, I put the expand and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the listview is taking infinite height  If you add shrinkwrap, it will take just enough height for the list to display.

You might have use Flexible() also if that doesn't solve

Add shrinkwrap =true

On

`Listview.builder(
....
shrinkWrap:true. 
),`

If still doesn't solve, wrap the Listview or the widget containing it which is child of column into Flexible.

`Flexible(flex:1,child :list/widget containing list)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work I tried it in 2 ways